# Where to put a class shared by child namespace?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

Traditional wisdom says not to call into child namespaces from a parent.

Let's say I'm using something like **AutoMapper** to translate content models into viewmodels for an ASP.NET MVC 3 site.

My directory structure looks similar to this:

```
- Stuff.Content
    -Foo.cs
- Stuff.Content.Public
    -Controllers
        -FooController.cs
    -Models
        -FooViewModel.cs
    -Views
        -Foo
            -Index.cshtml
 - AutoMapperConfig.cs
 - Global.asax
```

**AutoMapperConfig.cs** in this case is just a simple static class with a static method to set up the mapping, and looks like this:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooViewModel>();
    }
}
```

You'll notice I've got **AutoMapperConfig** in the root of the public project, but it's actually calling into a child namespace (**Stuff.Content.Public.Models**).

Is calling into that child namespace acceptable? Should **AutoMapperConfig** live in the **Models** namespace with the viewmodels?

It seems like it gets fuzzy in this territory since it's considered normal for controllers in the **Controllers** namespace to call its sibling **Models** namespace.

Looking forward to your thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your current design. Personally I put the mapping configurations into a `Mappings` subfolder folder:

```
- Stuff.Content
    -Foo.cs
- Stuff.Content.Public
    -Controllers
        -FooController.cs
    -Models
        -FooViewModel.cs
    -Views
        -Foo
            -Index.cshtml
    -Mappings
        -AutoMapperConfig.cs
 - Global.asax
```

Also I tend to have a separate mapping file definition for each domain model.

```
-Mappings
   -MappingRegistry.cs
   -FooProfile.cs
   -BarProfile.cs
   -...
```

And here's an example of `FooProfile.cs`:

```
public class FooProfile: Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Foo, FooViewModel>();
    }
}
```

and `MappingRegistry.cs`:

```
public static class MappingRegistry
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(
            x => typeof(MappingRegistry)
                .Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(type => !type.IsAbstract && typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(type => x.AddProfile((Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(type)))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's cool, but if I understand you correctly you've got a seperate profile for each type to be mapped. What's the advantage to doing that setup (and using reflection) as opposed to just calling create map on each inside a single configure in one class?